# Discord.js - UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: RangeError [MESSAGE_NONCE_TYPE]: Message nonce must fit in an unsigned 64-bit integer

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I'm currently working on a Discord bot (using discord.js) and I'm getting the following error, but only randomly: `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: RangeError [MESSAGE_NONCE_TYPE]: Message nonce must fit in an unsigned 64-bit integer`.

It appears the error is coming from Discord's API, but I'm not sure why exactly - again, it occurs randomly it seems, so hard to narrow down the cause. Any advice?

This is the rest of the error:

```
at APIMessage.resolveData (node_modules\discord.js\src\structures\APIMessage.js:155:44)
    at TextChannel.send (node_modules\discord.js\src\structures\interfaces\TextBasedChannel.js:166:62)
    at Message.reply (node_modules\discord.js\src\structures\Message.js:562:25)
    at Object.execute (commands\skill.js:12:24)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
```

Comment: that wasn't sarcasm - you haven't shown any code, so there's no way to know if you're doing something wrong - ahh, I see you don't define the message nonce ... sorry then

Comment: are you receiving a message nonce or dealing with one in any way? what function is throwing that error?

Comment: Added the rest of the error message. I am not changing, receiving, or dealing with a message nonce myself in any way. My code (the commands\skill.js) is simply doing a `return message.reply()`.

Comment: OK, I see - that's odd

Comment: I'm getting the same error