# RangeError: Message nonce must fit in an unsigned 64-bit integer

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

Here's the code that throws this error:

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();

client.on('message', (message) => {
    if (message.author === client.user) return;
    message.channel.send(message);
});

client.login(token);
```

The code makes the bot echo all users and bots. It runs fine normally, but fails with the title error when the message contains an image attachment or an embed. Here's the stacktrace:

```sql
(node:12192) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: RangeError [MESSAGE_NONCE_TYPE]: Message nonce must fit in an unsigned 64-bit integer.
    at APIMessage.resolveData (C:\Users\redbrain\node_modules\discord.js\src\structures\APIMessage.js:155:44)
    at TextChannel.send (C:\Users\redbrain\node_modules\discord.js\src\structures\interfaces\TextBasedChannel.js:166:62)
    at Client.<anonymous> (C:\Users\redbrain\Documents\chatbots\movebot\index.js:31:14)
    at Client.emit (events.js:310:20)
    at MessageCreateAction.handle (C:\Users\redbrain\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\actions\MessageCreate.js:31:14)
    at Object.module.exports [as MESSAGE_CREATE] (C:\Users\redbrain\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\handlers\MESSAGE_CREATE.js:4:32)
    at WebSocketManager.handlePacket (C:\Users\redbrain\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketManager.js:384:31)
    at WebSocketShard.onPacket (C:\Users\redbrain\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:444:22)
    at WebSocketShard.onMessage (C:\Users\redbrain\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:301:10)
    at WebSocket.onMessage (C:\Users\redbrain\node_modules\discord.js\node_modules\ws\lib\event-target.js:125:16)
```

I understand there is a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64002528/discord-js-unhandledpromiserejectionwarning-rangeerror-message-nonce-type) but it was never answered and the question wasn't detailed.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: `message` is a *very* complex object, making it impossible to send. I believe you're looking for `message.content`, the actual text in the message. Also, did you define `bot`?

Comment: Thanks @Lioness100 ! Looks like I can't resend the `Message` object, so I'll just manually copy from it all the attributes that I can send and put those into a new `ApiMessage` to send. Also, `bot` is the name of the `Discord.Client` in my code, but I tried to change it to `client` when i posted the code snippet for clarity to others. I missed that one and I'll edit it to be correct. If you wouldn't mind answering the question so it appears closed to others I'd be grateful. Once again thanks for your help.